# Output the number of unique characters in an object

Tags: c++, vector, unique

I need to call the method to return a list of cities a person has visited from a Person object and traverse that list and print them out one by one (which I already have done). Now, I have to print out the number of unique cities that person has visited but have no idea how. How do I do this simply (I'm only at a polytechnic grade)? I have this so far.

```
Person *person1 = new Person(listOfCities);

for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
{
    cout << "Please enter name of city: ";
    cin >> cityName; 

    cout << "Please enter size of city: "; 
    cin >> citySize; 

    cout << "Please enter postal code of city: "; 
    cin >> postalCode; 

    cout << " " << endl;

    City myCity(cityName, citySize, postalCode); 

    person1->addCity(myCity);
}

for (int k = 0; k < person1->returnListOfCities().size(); k++) 
{
    cout << person1->returnListOfCities()[k].toString() << endl; 
}
```

The toString() method displays the name, size and postal code of the city.
listOfCities is stored in a vector.

Answer (score 0):

assuming cities is a std::string, you can take guidelines from the following snippet:

```
#include <string>
#include <set>
#include <iostream>

using std::set;
using std::string;
using std::cout;
using std::cin;

int main()
{
    string s;
    set<string> cities;
    char response = 'y';
    while (response == 'y')
    {
        cout << "Enter name of city:\t";
        cin >> s;
        cities.insert(s);
        cout << "Continue (y/n): ";
        cin >> response;
    }
    cout << "Total cities travelled:\t" << cities.size();
}
```

Well, I used a container called 'set' to store the cities visited. Enough to give you ideas.

More info on set here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/

Just forgot to add: its case-sensitive, so Toronto and toronto will be treated differently.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are stuck with a `std::vector` and cannot use `std::set`. Sample for printing unique element in vector below

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v = { 1, 4, 1, 1, 2 };

    //std::unique works with sorted array only 
    std::sort( v.begin(), v.end() );

    //size of vector is not modified. But duplicate elements are overwritten with non duplicates
    // { 1, 2, 4, ?, ? }
    std::vector< int >::iterator endLocation;
    endLocation = std::unique( v.begin(), v.end() );

    //print unique elements
    std::ostream_iterator< int > output( std::cout, " " );
    std::copy( v.begin(), endLocation, output );

    return 0;
}
```

Note 1: std::unique alters the existing array. So create a copy if vector has to be used again

Note 2: This involves sorting of `std::vector` which **alone** works at `O( n log n )`. If the number of elements in `std::vector` is large, it **might** be better to create `std::set` which maintains only unique elements and it's insertion complexity would be `O( log n )` for hashing algorithms used in `std::set`. But that would create a duplicate of all unique elements ( more space constraints ). It would be as below.

```
std::set<int> uniqueElements( v.begin(), v.end() );
```